# Positioning of multiple stacked bar plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a multiple stacked bar plot with pandas.

Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10, 20], 'b': [15, 25], 'c': [35, 40], 'd':[45, 50]}, index=['john', 'bob'])

ax = df[['a', 'c']].plot.bar(position=0, width=0.1, stacked=True)
df[['b', 'd']].plot.bar(position=1, width=0.1, stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

Which, in a notebook, give the following output: [image: stacked bar plot]

The problem I'm facing is that, for each group, the bars are not in the order I want them to be. The doc says that the "position" argument for a bar plot specifies the relative position of the bar, with 0 being left and 1 being right. But it seems to do the complete opposite. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position parameter in [`pd.Df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)controls the alignment of your bar plot layouts. It resembles similarity with the [`align`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) parameter of a matplotlib bar plot.

Illustrations:  
1. when `position=0.5`: [Default : center alignment]

```
df[['a', 'c']].plot.bar(position=0.5, width=0.1, stacked=True, ax=ax)
df[['b', 'd']].plot.bar(position=0.5, width=0.1, stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

The bars are coinciding with the X-axis labels as shown:
[image]
2. when `position=0`:[left/bottom edge alignment]

```
df[['a', 'c']].plot.bar(position=0, width=0.1, stacked=True, ax=ax)
df[['b', 'd']].plot.bar(position=0, width=0.1, stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

The left most portion of the bars are coinciding with the X-axis labels as shown:
[image]

Now, you can clearly distinguish the difference between the above 2 figures.

Comment: great answer, thanks! Here is then a follow up question: What is the proper way using pandas' plotting feature to plot a multiple stacked bar plot? I will have something like 4 bars per "group". Please tell me if you think I should create a new post instead

Comment: I feel that would be better. You could also include a sample `dataframe` in that post too.